# How to get value of custom Attribute whose ID and Name is not defined? - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get value of Custom attribute of Markup element through JQuery, whose ID and Name is not defined.

```
<div questionId="Question_1.1"></div>
```

I tried following but getting undefined every time:

```
$("input[questionId]").val();
$("#questionId").val();
$("input[questionId]").val();
```

On Page Load, i want to change opacity of this div.

Comment: You should really think about using valid custom attribute: `data-question-id` e.g...

Answer (score 3):

It isn't an `<input>`:

```
$("div[questionId]").html();
```

If you want to get the attribute `questionId`'s value, use `attr`:

```
$("div[questionId]").attr('questionId');
```

Just another thing to think about, but in HTML5, a custom attribute isn't valid unless it starts with `data-` such as `data-questionid`.

> The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

<sup>[Source](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)</sup>

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p183ojcg/1/)

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, use jQuery `.each()` if you have multiple divs:

```
$("div[questionId]").each(function(){
$(this).animate({'opacity':3},300);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p183ojcg/3/)

Comment: A DIV hasn't any value property

Comment: @A.Wolff yep, was just about to change that :D

Comment: Ya, for selector but this isn't really answering OP question. I guess he wants the attribute value: `$("div[questionId]").attr('questionId')`. But question is not clear imho

Comment: it is valid for one div only.
What if i have multiple divs, with same attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the div using jQuery like this:

```
var div = $('div[questionId="Question_1.1"]');
```

So, if the div `questionId` is being entered in a text input, you can grab the input value and select the appropriate div like this:

```js
// get the input value:
var id = $('input').val();

var div = $('div[questionId="' + id + '"]');

// jQuery's "fade" function fadeTo()
div.fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
```

```css
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Question_1.1" />
<div questionId="Question_1.1">Question 1.1</div>
```